# Posting using WinHttpSendRequest

Tags: c++, winapi, winhttp

How do you create a form to post using WinHttpSendRequest?

For example: if I know

```
name=Johnson;
subject=Hi;
message=Hi;
```

How do i send it using the function?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to format it yourself according to the spec ([application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1)).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to http://yeilho.blogspot.com/2011/07/winhttpsendrequest.html